# Решение СЛАУ

Tags: c, алгоритм, c++

Доброго времени суток!
После прогонки бинарной матрицы через метод гаусса получаем конечную матрицу. 
Вопрос такой:  как из этой матрицы получить все наборы векторов-решений?
Как это сделать вручную - знаю. Но вопрос чисто в программной реализации.
Заранее спасибо!
P.S.  матрица над кольцом вычетов по модулю 2.

Comment: А в чём конкретно проблема? Какую из операций, которые вы можете сделать «вручную», вы не можете закодировать?

Comment: когда нужно выражать базисные переменные через свободные при всех возможных значениях последних, я несколько не понимаю, как выписать все вектора решений.  
точнее, не понимаю, как это сделать с минимальным количеством действий.  
мой код на полсотни страниц выглядит примерно так   http://s2.developerslife.ru/public/images/gifs/0371b158-be80-420b-a183-17722981310f.gif  
и совершает кучу операций по матрице, а так же, по дополнительно созданным массивам различных отметок, таких как положения базисных и свободных переменных, их количество и тд

Comment: Подождите, количество векторов решений будет равно просто количеству свободных переменных, без степени двойки. Нужно сделать так:

1) После прямого хода у нас есть таблица «переименования переменных». Откладываем её рассмотрение до самого конца, временно можно считать все переменные с номерами меньше `r` базисными, а остальные свободными.  

2) Не забываем обратный ход. Наша матрица должна стать единичной, если рассматривать только базисные элементы.

3) К-во решений равно к-ву свободных переменных. Выписываем вектора решений: в i-ом векторе i-ая свободная переменная равна 1, ...

Comment: 3) ... остальные 0, а координаты, соответствующие базисным переменным, определяем по матрице: `j`-ая координата получается из `j`-ого уравнения (видите?) и равна просто b_j - a_ij x_i (т.к. остальные свободные переменные равны нулю).

4) Получив все вектора решений, переставляем в них координаты по таблице из пункта 1)

Вроде получается несложно. Выкладывайте код по кусочкам, подчистим, сделаем как надо.

PS: Ваша картинка лучше смотрится [с музыкой](http://blueballfixed.ytmnd.com/) (только сделайте звук потише, я предупредил).

Comment: меня смущает ваш пункт №3: приведу пример. пусть у нас есть матрица:  
110011  
010011  
101000  
001000  
000000  
000101  
общее решение: x1=0,x3=0,x4=x5,x2=x5+x6.  
x5 и x6 - свободные.но решений будет не 2 а 3:  
(0101 01),(0100 10),(0001 11) (без нулевого) тогда будет 2^(кол-во_свободных_переменных)-1 векторов решений  
то, что вы описали, действительно, несложно. вот так я реализовал(хотя, что-то мне подсказывает, что количество телодвижений к этом коде можно сократить)  
http://codepad.org/UB4fQJ8n  
но решение (000111) теряется

Comment: Не-не-не, подождите, так не может быть. Решение для x5 = 1, x6 = 1 обязано быть суммой решений для x5 = 1, x6 = 0 и x5 = 0, x6 = 1. В вашем случае общее решение вроде бы x1 = 0, x2 = -x5-x6, x3 = 0, x4=-x6, базисные решения (0 -1 0 0 1 0), (0 -1 0 -1 0 1), решение с x5 = x6 = 1: (0 -2 0 -1 1 1) есть сумма базисных решений. Если я не ошибся в вычислениях.

Comment: Но это не отменяет мои вычисления. В Z_2 получаем: общее решение x1 = 0, x2 = x5+x6, x3 = 0, x4=x6, базисные решения (0 1 0 0 1 0), (0 1 0 1 0 1), решение с x5 = x6 = 1: (0 0 0 1 1 1) есть сумма базисных решений. Базисные решения не дают все возможные решения: остальные решения получаются как линейные комбинации базисных.

Comment: решение данной СЛАУ есть часть метода квадратичного решета и нужны именно все решения, а не только базисные, дабы получить сразу несколько делителей или уменьшить шанс получения тривиальных делителей.  
и, как мне кажется, более быстрый вариант - сразу сгенерировать все решения, чем потом искать их, выражая через басисные.  
поправьте, пожалуйста, если я не прав.

Comment: А разницы по большому счёту вообще нет. Каждое решение есть линейная комбинация базисных, для каждого набора значений свободных переменных полученное решение есть линейная комбинация базисных с коэффициентами, равными значениям этих самых свободных переменных. Вопрос лишь в удобстве.

Comment: Ясно.   
Спасибо большое за помощь!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Собственно, в итоге получаем приведенный ниже код.
Ответ -  набор базисных решений.
Если необходимы *все* решения, то
"для каждого набора значений свободных переменных полученное решение есть линейная комбинация базисных с коэффициентами, равными значениям этих самых свободных переменных."

```
std::vector< boost::dynamic_bitset<> > Matrix(row,boost::dynamic_bitset<>(col,0));    
 ...
//метод гаусса
std::vector<int> where(col,-1); int used_row=0;
for(int c=0,r=0;c<col && r<row;c++){
    for(int i=r;i<row;i++)
        if(Matrix[i][c]){
            swap(Matrix[i],Matrix[r]);
            break;
        }
    if(! Matrix[r][c]) continue;
    where[c]=r; used_row++;
    for(int i=0;i<row;i++)
        if(i!=r && Matrix[i][c])
            Matrix[i]^=Matrix[r];
        r++;
}
//удаляем нулевые строки
Matrix.erase(Matrix.begin()+used_row,Matrix.begin()+row-1);
row=used_row;
//находим номера свободных и базисных переменных
std::vector<int> free;
std::vector<int> base;
int ans_num=0;
for(int i=0;i<col;i++)
    if(where[i]==-1){
        free.push_back(i);
        ans_num++;
    }
    else
        base.push_back(i);
//заполняем вектора ответов
std::vector< boost::dynamic_bitset<> > ans(ans_num,boost::dynamic_bitset<>(col,0));
for(int i=0;i<ans_num;i++){
    ans[i][free[i]]=1;
    for(int j=0;j<col-ans_num;j++)
        ans[i][base[j]]=Matrix[j][base[j]]*Matrix[j][free[i]];
}
```

---

на самом деле, можно уменьшить количество прохождений по массиву, для этого мы не будем удалять нулевые строки(мы уже использовали эту память и совсем скоро ее вовсе освободим), а так же искать базисные и свободны переменные и их количество во время преобразования матрицы к ступенчатому виду:

```
std::vector< boost::dynamic_bitset<> > Matrix(row,boost::dynamic_bitset<>(col,0));    
...
//метод гаусса
std::vector<int> base;      //базисные переменные
std::vector<int> free;      //свободные переменные
int ans_num=0;//количество векторов ответов, равное количеству свободных переменных
for(int c=0,r=0;c<col && r<row;c++){
    for(int i=r;i<row;i++)
        if(Matrix[i][c]){
            swap(Matrix[i],Matrix[r]);
            break;
        }
    if(! Matrix[r][c]){
        free.push_back(c); 
        ans_num++;
        continue;
    }
    base.push_back(c);
    for(int i=0;i<row;i++)
        if(i!=r && Matrix[i][c])
            Matrix[i]^=Matrix[r];
    r++;
}
//заполняем вектора ответов
std::vector< boost::dynamic_bitset<> > ans(ans_num,boost::dynamic_bitset<>(col,0));
for(int i=0;i<ans_num;i++){
    ans[i][free[i]]=1;
    for(int j=0;j<col-ans_num;j++)
        ans[i][base[j]]=Matrix[j][base[j]]*Matrix[j][free[i]];
}
```

---

Большое спасибо [VladD](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/10105/vladd) за помощь

Comment: Для большей читаемости кода я бы разбил его на процедуры. Отдельно прямой ход, отдельно обратный, отдельно заполнение ответа. Ещё можно выделить процедуру умножения вектора-строки на вектор-столбец. Возможно, нужны ещё соответствующие классы и операции над ними. Кода станет больше, но выглядеть будет проще и более читаемо.

И ещё класс «решатель СЛАУ», не передавать же всякие штуки типа количества ненулевых строк через параметры во внутренние процедуры?